# How to set all auto increments to 1 in a Schema

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

Is it possible to reset all auto increment in a schema in one query? if not even just by per table will do. btw I am using MySQL server 8 thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is not normally something to do with `AUTO_INCREMENT`; please explain the use case.  We may have a simpler way to achieve the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autoincrement is seeded by certain number by `ALTER TABLE` query that can operate one and only one table at the time. So you have to run the  `ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT=1;` for each and every table in your scheme having the autoincremented columns.

Answer (score 2):

If the tables already have rows, you can't do it.

If you want to throw away all the data, then you could do `TRUNCATE TABLE` for each table.

Or you could get all the table definitions via `mysqldump --no-data` and make sure there are `DROP TABLE` for each.  Then have a script that runs the output.